# Unresolved externals and extern "C"?

Tags: c++, c, extern-c

As new as I am to C++, I don´t fully understand this linking and stuff.
And I think this is about `extern "C"` linking.

```
extern "C"
{
int loadbmp(char *filename, unsigned char **buf,
            int *w, int *h, int pf, int bottomup);
const char *bmpgeterr(void);
}

unsigned char *srcBuf=NULL, **jpegBuf=NULL;
unsigned long jpegsize=0;
int width, height;
char *filename={"Screenshot158139.bmp"};
tjhandle handle=NULL;

void main(){
    if(loadbmp(filename, &srcBuf, &width, &height,TJPF_RGB, 0)==-1){
        //printf("Could not load bitmap: %s\n", bmpgeterr());
        exit(1);
    }
    if((handle=tjInitCompress())==NULL) {
        printf("Could not initialize compressor: %s\n", tjGetErrorStr());
        free(srcBuf);
        exit(1);
    }
    if((tjCompress2(handle, srcBuf, width, 0, height, TJPF_RGB,
                    jpegBuf, &jpegsize, TJSAMP_444,10, 0))==-1) {
        printf("Could not compress: %s\n", tjGetErrorStr());
        free(&srcBuf);
        tjDestroy(handle);
        exit(1);
    }    
}
```

The problem I get from this is that I need to resolve the `extern "C"` code I think:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol loadbmp
```

Sadly, I don´t know how to do that, and as this error is extremely common in the C++ world, finding an answer for this is not that easy as they can differ.

Hopefully it´s pretty easy to solve this, as I guess I must define it or something as it´s external code.

Comment: section number 7 from the C++ standard if I'm remembering correctly.

Comment: The only portable return type of `main()` is `int`.

Comment: Just a general tip: Literal strings are *constant*, so you should either declares variables pointing to a literal string as either `const char* filename = "...";` or like an array as in `char filename[] = "...";`.

Comment: Meaning, i can´t use Void? Is there any difference if so? cause i mean, main is the loop, the actual program. Why does it have to have a value?

Comment: As for your problem, you're missing to link with a file when building, either a library file or an object file.

Comment: Regarding the `void` return from `main`, the C specifications (a couple of revisions of them) specifies that `main` *must* return `int`. Anything else will most likely work, but is unspecified behavior.

Comment: Hmm, probably the loadbmp file i can´t seem to find, so i ended up writing it in the main code, weird that i have to link still.

Comment: @user2587718 - **all** c/c++ programs require linking.

Comment: @user2587718: Using `void` as the return type for `main()` doesn't have to be supported by a compiler and some compilers do warn about it. I'm not aware of any compiler which does rejected. As to why they return type of `main()` has to be `int`, one of the reasons is that on some systems programs always have a result value which needs to be set up.

Comment: @user2587718: Just because you wrote a *declaration* in your "main code" doesn't mean the compiler/linker can figure out why it is *defined*! Linking is the process of finding the definitions of the various declarations and the linker will only go looking for definitions in the libraries you specified and in the standard libraries.

Comment: Are you actually linking to the library that provides the `loadbmp` routine (opengl?). That's the most common reason for it not linking properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have declared `loadbmp()` but you haven't defined it. Where is the function defined? If it is supposed to come from a library, **do not** declare this function yourself but rather include the relevant header. The documentation of the function should tell you which is the relevant header and it should mention which extra libraries you may need to include.

If `loadbmp()` isn't function you want to take from a library, you need to define (implement) it.

Comment: I´ts from a library, or header (Turbojpeg), sadly, i don´t get how to import it. i have added all the libraries, but this particular thing (loadbmp) doesn´t exist, but i can see it in the source files, which is why i tried add it myself.

Comment: Well this is still an answer to the question, the rest is up to me to find this stuff. Thanks

Comment: Briefly looking for that stuff it seems that there is an open source library called [`libjpeg-turbo`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/) providing a signature like the one you declared. Did you install this library and included it appropriately into your build?

Comment: If this is from a library, you can't declare it furthermore, you need to just call it and include the suitable header file for compilattion and .lib file for linking

Comment: I have included the libjpeg-turbo libraries, and the headers, everything else seems to be detected, but i think the loadbmp was some special case, will ask the author more about it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is linking to your `.lib` file. Often a quick and easy way is to add this line to the top of the file

`#pragma comment(lib,"put_your_lib_filename_here.lib")`